# Using Leibniz on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

> Using Leibniz on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+1})$

So the question actually is how to rewrite $\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})$ in the form of $(-1)^n\times a_n$ so that I can apply Leibniz and decide the convergence or divergence?

I'm sorry but I'm pretty new in studying *series*.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170786/62839) should help you.

Comment: @user1337 And how do you prove the first trig identity from that answer?

Comment: This is just the identity for the sine of a sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$\sqrt{n^2+1}
=n+d(n)$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})
&=\sin(\pi(n+d(n))\\
&=\sin(\pi n)\cos(\pi d(n))
+\cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi d(n))\\
&=(-1)^n\sin(\pi d(n))\\
\end{array}
$

Also

$\begin{array}\\
d(n)
&=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\\
&=(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$0 < d(n)
\lt \dfrac1{2n}$
and $d(n)$
is decreasing
so that,
since $\sin(x)$ is
increasing for
$-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$,
$\sin(\pi d(n))$
is also decreasing.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin(\pi d(n))
$
converges by the
alternating series test.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)=\sin\left(\pi n\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}\right)\sim\sin\left(\pi n\left(1+\frac1{2n^2}\right)\right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)\sim(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2n}.$$